# How is this listArray populated?

Tags: haskell

Having correctly answered [euler question 92](https://projecteuler.net/problem=92) using a brute force solution I read through the thread 92 looking for other haskell solutions. The last solution is blisteringly fast but has me stumped as to how it implements an array showing if the numbers 0 to 567 boil down to chains ending in 1 (False) or 89 (True).

```
import Data.List
import Data.Array
import Data.Char

b = (is89!) . sum . map ((^2) . digitToInt) . show
is89 = listArray (0, 567) $ False:False:(map b [2..88] ++ [True] ++ map b [90..567])
```

I thought I understood the lazy nature of haskell and the way it can use prior values in lists to generate future values such as in generating primes, fibonacci numbers or such like. But in this instance the indexes seem to dance about (within the bounds of 0 to 567) and I am lost as to how the value of an index ends up False or True.

For instance the first value in the first map is 2 which when squared and summed is 4. But index 4 has not been prepopulated yet. The only values prepopulated as far as I can see are 0,1 and 89.

Could someone walk me through slowly how this array is populated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Haskell's laziness is also about calculating every value only once, and this array is a rather classical memoization technique.

So we are asked to calculate `is89 ! 2`, we check the array and see that the element has not yet been evaluated, then we follow the definition and see that to evaluate it, we need to evaluate `is89 ! 4`, so we do that. Again we check the array and see that it isn't evaluated yet. And so on, we check `16`, `37`, `58`, and then finally arrive at `89`, we check the array and see that the value has been evaluated! (Per definition it is `True`). Then we backtrack and update the index `58` to also "be evaluated" and contain `True`, and so on with `37`, `16`, `4`, and `2`, and this is when we return and say that the value we were asked is `True`.

Next time, suppose, that we are asked `is89 ! 11`, we check the array, and see that it is not evaluated yet, and that we need `is89 ! 2`, but we already evaluated that one earlier! So we just use the result of the evaluation from the past.

In the end we have achieved a lookup table that is only populated with values that are demanded, i.e memoization.

Comment: I guess the place where my understanding falters is when you say: _we check the array and see that the element has not yet been evaluated, then we follow the definition and see that to evaluate it, we need to evaluate is89 ! 4, so we do that_. How come, where did this spring from? BTHW isn't the first index 4 not 2?

Comment: @potong, In haskell (specifically STG-based implemtation like GHC), every value is either an evaluated value, or a closure (a piece of code) explaining how to evaluate it, and when that code is executed, the closure is replaced with the evaluated value.